# Get the Custom categories in json format : Call to undefined method Ultimate_Mars_Helper_Category::getCategorys()

Tags: magento-1.9

I created Custom Category Tree using [Ultimate Module Creator  module](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9)  by following [github link](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki/crud)

**Magento Default Category Tree** :

[image]

**Ultimate Module Creator module Tree** [ **UMC** ]:

[image]

I found that with help of below code we can display default categories in json format....

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');

$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();

$category = array();

foreach($_categories as $_category)
{
     $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());    
     $category[] = array("name" => $_category->getName(), "id" => $_category->getId());
}

 echo json_encode($category);

?>
```

Result :

[image]

**Requirement** :

but how to display custom categories [UMC] in json format ?

Custom categories are nothing but **Entities** in UMC module....

[image]

app/code/local/Ultimate/Mars/Model - **Category.php**

```
 <?php

class Ultimate_Mars_Model_Category extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Entity code.
     * Can be used as part of method name for entity processing
     */
    const ENTITY    = 'ultimate_mars_category';
    const CACHE_TAG = 'ultimate_mars_category';

    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'ultimate_mars_category';

    /**
     * Parameter name in event
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'category';


    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('ultimate_mars/category');
    }


    public function getTreeModel()
    {
        return Mage::getResourceModel('ultimate_mars/category_tree');
    }


    public function getTreeModelInstance()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_treeModel)) {
            $this->_treeModel = Mage::getResourceSingleton('ultimate_mars/category_tree');
        }
        return $this->_treeModel;
    }

    public function getParentCategory()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('parent_category')) {
            $this->setData(
                'parent_category',
                Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category')->load($this->getParentId())
            );
        }
        return $this->_getData('parent_category');
    }


    public function getParentId()
    {
        $parentIds = $this->getParentIds();
        return intval(array_pop($parentIds));
    }


    public function getParentIds()
    {
        return array_diff($this->getPathIds(), array($this->getId()));
    }

    public function checkId($id)
    {
        return $this->_getResource()->checkId($id);
    }


    public function getPathIds()
    {
        $ids = $this->getData('path_ids');
        if (is_null($ids)) {
            $ids = explode('/', $this->getPath());
            $this->setData('path_ids', $ids);
        }
        return $ids;
    }



    public function getCategorys($parent, $recursionLevel = 0, $sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true)
    {
        return $this->getResource()->getCategorys($parent, $recursionLevel, $sorted, $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }


    public function getParentCategorys()
    {
        return $this->getResource()->getParentCategorys($this);
    } 

    public function getStatusPath()
    {
        $parents = $this->getParentCategorys();
        $rootId = Mage::helper('ultimate_mars/category')->getRootCategoryId();
        foreach ($parents as $parent) {
            if ($parent->getId() == $rootId) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!$parent->getStatus()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return $this->getStatus();
    }



}
```

app/code/local/Ultimate/Mars/Helper - **Category.php**

```
class Ultimate_Mars_Helper_Category extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const CATEGORY_ROOT_ID = 1;
    /**
     * get the root id
     *
     * @access public
     * @return int
     * @author Ultimate Module Creator
     */
    public function getRootCategoryId()
    {
        return self::CATEGORY_ROOT_ID;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I tried below code, but it did't worked for me....

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);

Mage::app('default');
set_time_limit(0);  
require_once('app/Mage.php');

$_rootId = Mage::helper('ultimate_mars/category');
$_categories = $_rootId->getCategorys();

$category = array();

foreach($_categories as $_category)
{    
     $_category = Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category')->getCategorys($_rootId);
     $category[] = array("name" => $_category->getName(), "id" => $_category->getId());
}

 echo json_encode($category);

?>
```

**Error** : **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Ultimate_Mars_Helper_Category::getCategorys()**

[Here is link to Download module](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1em4p6d2FJyu8mQ7GQDlHlwIUtDwReAvc) : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1em4p6d2FJyu8mQ7GQDlHlwIUtDwReAvc)

Comment: The function you are trying to call is from Ultimate_Mars_Helper_Category (**Helper**), while the function has been defined in the **Model** class. Please check and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Thanks for support, i got solution.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$cat_model = Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category');
$_categories = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array('gt' => 1));

$category = array();
foreach($_categories as $_category)
{
    $category[] = array("name" => $_category->getCategoryname(), "id" => $_category->getEntityId());
}

echo json_encode($category);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the code into your below helper file.

```
app/code/local/Ultimate/Mars/Helper - Category.php

class Ultimate_Mars_Helper_Category extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const CATEGORY_ROOT_ID = 1;

    public function getRootCategoryId()
    {
        return self::CATEGORY_ROOT_ID;
    }

    public function getCategorys()
    {
        $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
        $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
        return $_categories;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried your code & i got `Fatal error: Cannot declare class Ultimate_Mars_Helper_Category, because the name is already in use ` , other solution worked for me.....